# Print value blocks into new worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that I need to split out into new ones by column C values. There are 8 values, so I'll need 8 worksheets. Each value has about 2-5000 corresponding rows, so this script isn't ideal because it prints row-by-row.

```
Sub SplitData()
    Const iCol = 3 ' names in second column (B)
    Const sRow = 2 ' data start in row 2

    Dim wshSource As Worksheet
    Dim wshTarget As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lngTargetRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wshSource = Sheets(1)

    lRow = wshSource.Cells(wshSource.Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = sRow To lRow

        If wshSource.Cells(i, iCol).Value <> wshSource.Cells(i - 1, iCol).Value Then
            Set wshTarget = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
            wshTarget.Name = wshSource.Cells(i, iCol).Value
            wshSource.Rows(sRow - 1).Copy Destination:=wshTarget.Cells(1, 1)
            lngTargetRow = 2
        End If

        wshSource.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=wshTarget.Cells(lngTargetRow, 1)
        lngTargetRow = lngTargetRow + 1
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

How would I change this up to print each value block (column C) to each worksheet instead of every row (i) individually? Would I need to implement auto-filtering by column C values and do a loop that way?

Comment: Move the `Worksheets.Add` outside the `i` loop, and make it conditional to "a new block" being entered in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out, as you well pointed, filtering would be the fastest way here:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim uniqueValues As Object
    Set uniqueValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim i As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MainSheet") 'change MainSheet to the name of the sheet containing the data

        'First let's store the unique values inside a dictionary
        For i = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count 'this will loop till the last used row
            If Not uniqueValues.Exists(.Cells(i, 3).Value) Then uniqueValues.Add .Cells(i, 3).Value, 1
        Next i

        'Now let's loop through the unique values
        Dim Key As Variant
        For Each Key In uniqueValues.Keys
            .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Key 'Filter column C by the value in the key
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count) 'add a new sheet
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Name = Key 'change the name of the new sheet to the key's
            .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Key).Range("A1") 'copy the visible range after the filter to the new sheet
        Next Key
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: quick question, how do I omit blanks when it adds the unique keys? Would I wrap something like `if key.value <> ""`type of statement after the `For Each Key in UniqueValues.Keys`?

Comment: like this `If Not uniqueValues.Exists(.Cells(i, 3).Value) And Not .Cells(i, 3) = vbNullString Then` it will skip the blanks upon filling the dictionary, so it will skip them later on also.